# Getting formula from points (for a maths problem)

Tags: functions

So last night I remembered a question in a kids magazine about a witch flying on her broom. She flies one way with the wind and back against it. Would it be faster to go without wind or would it not matter?

I made a formula:
$$ \frac {t_1+t_2} {t_0} = \frac {2LS^2} {2L(S^2-W^2)} $$
where 
$t_1$ is speed to forward with wind, 
$t_2$ is speed back against wind, 
$t_0$ is speed forward and back with no wind, 
$L$ is one-way distance, 
$S$ is speed, and 
$W$ is wind’s speed.

Looking at it, it makes sense - the bigger wind, the bigger difference between no wind and with wind trip. I also tested in Excel with manual calculation (10 km road, 10 km/h speed, wind from 0-10 km/h).

But I still would like to get a formula to get time difference (in ratio) from ratio of speed and speed of wind. In Excel I added my calculated points and it resulted in this:
[image]

Which clearly means ($Y$ is ratio of speeds, so 50 means 10 km/h and 0.2 km/h; $X$ is ratio of times with and without wind) that wind has to be as little as possible (or zero, as function reaches infinity near $X=1$).

My question - what is the formula for this function? Is it a hyperbola, or is $Y=1/X$ type of function? I left school quite some time ago. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it appears you already have what your looking for, try instead of drawing graphs and getting a formula from the shape of the graph, look at what formulas you used to plot the graph in the first place.

If we take your equation $\frac{t_1+t_2}{t_0}=\frac{2LS^2}{2L(S^2-W^2)}$ and cancel the $2L$ term on the right hand side we get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{t_1+t_2}{t_0}=\frac{S^2}{(S^2-W^2)}
\end{align}$$
Which is exactly a formula for the ratio of 'wind affected' over 'non wind affected' times in terms of speed and wind speed only.

We can also rearrange this to get the ratio of speed to wind speed in terms of 'wind affected' and 'non wind affected' times:
$$\frac{S}{W}=\sqrt{\frac{t_1+t_2}{t_0+t_1+t_2}}$$
Hopefully this is what you where looking for.

Comment: Yes! Somehow I did not see '2L' to cancel, but how did you get the final formula?

Comment: @RiDi If you just take the first formula and rearange it to make $\frac{S}{W}$ the subject. It may not feel immediately obvious but try cross multiplying then multiplying out the brackets and everything falls into place quite well.